# How to write nested if statements in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query in SQL Server 2008 like below:

```
declare @checkValue int = 1
IF (@checkValue = 1)
(
     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#newtable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #newtable
     Select Id
     into #newtable
     From #oldtable
);
```

This is not working since the second if clause which is inside the main IF clause. How can I fix it and use nested if statements like that?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What does "not working" mean?   are you getting an error?

Comment: having a syntax error. Richard's solution is working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Almost, but you need BEGIN and END instead of parenthesis:

```
declare @checkValue int = 1
IF (@checkValue = 1)
BEGIN
     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#newtable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #newtable
     Select Id
     into #newtable
     From #oldtable
END;
```